# Unable to execute file.exe with wine 4.0.4 in HPC

Tags: executable, wine

I have a `.exe` file that I need to run in HPC and I am not sure how to do this.
I tried using `wine-4.0.4` as follow but I get the following

```
chmod a+x Rtools35.exe
./Rtools35.exe

wine: Bad EXE format for my_path\Rtools35.exe
```

I have seen some people discussing the 32/64 bit issue but I don't think that is the issue and I have tried both versions of `.exe`.

I have never used wine again, can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!